# Can't set Type parameter in Method from Model at runtime C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, types

I am trying to set the type of a method at runtime. This happens when the user chooses a type from a drop down list. There are a number of different types that all inherit from the same interface.

Here is my code to explain the problem...

**Interface:**

```
public interface IFoo
{
     string Id { get; set; }
     string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Classes that implement `IFoo`:**

`Foo1`, `Foo2`, `Foo3`, `Foo4`, ...

**Classes Names put into a `List<string>` to show them in a dropdown on my MVC view:**

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllFooItems()
        {
            var a = typeof(IFoo).Assembly;

            var itemTypes = from type in a.GetTypes()
                            where type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IFoo))
                            select Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IFoo;

            return itemTypes.Select(instance => instance.GetType().Name).ToList();
        }
```

**Method to make the `List` above as an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for the drop down:**

```
private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems(IEnumerable<string> elements)
        {
            return elements.Select(element => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = element,
                Text = element
            }).ToList();
        }
```

Once a user chooses from the drop down list of `IFoo` items I want to use my model to set the Type of `IFoo` on the following **get method**:

```
public T Get<T>(string id) where T : IFoo
        {
            // do something
        }
```

Here is my **model**:

```
public class FooModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Item Id: ")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Content Type: ")]
        public IFoo FooItem { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FooItems { get; set; }
    }
```

And my **Controller**:

```
public class FooController : Controller
    {
        FooClient client = new FooClient("Foo"); // Placement of my Get Method (above)

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult FooSearch()
        {
            var fooTypes = GetAllFooItems();

            var model = new FooModel();
            model.FooItems = GetSelectListItems(fooTypes);

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FooSearch(FooModel model)
        {
            var fooTypes = GetAllFooItems();
            model.FooItems = GetSelectListItems(fooTypes);

            client.Get<model.FooItem>(model.id); // model.FooItem does not work

 // !!! I cannot set the Type from the model...

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            return View();
        }
   }
```

If anyone has an idea on how to change the Type parameter in the method based on the drop down selection I would be more than happy to find out. If you need more info let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to invoke the `Get` method like this:

```
var result = (IFoo) client.GetType()
    //get the generic Get<T> method
    .GetMethod("Get", new Type[] {typeof (string)}) 
    //get the specific Get<model.FooItem> method
    .MakeGenericMethod(model.FooItem.GetType()) 
    .Invoke(client, new object[] { model.id }); //Invoke the method
```

By the way, in the code where you get the names of the possible types, you don't have to create an instance of each type to get the names. Instead, you can do the following:

```
return (from type in a.GetTypes()
        where type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IFoo))
        select type.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Yacoub, thanks for your answer. Would I simply include this piece of code in my controller?

Comment: It replaces the invocation of the `Get` method (`client.Get<model.FooItem>(model.id);`)

Comment: Ok great, I'll test it :)

Comment: So this seems to be doing the trick. Thanks a lot. It seems though that I have a null on my `model.FooItem`. The dropdown does not select the item for some reason. But I'll debug the error :)